# Django Foreign Key to unmanaged model

Tags: django, django-models

Lets say I have these two simple models:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(max_length=9, primary_key=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'employee_view'
        managed = False
```

and

```
class Author(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
```

And I do:

```
e = Employee.objects.get(last_name='Tesla')
<Employee: Tesla>
```

I should be able to do:

```
a = Author.objects.create(employee=e)
```

But I get an integrity error and great sadness:

```
IntegrityError: (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`django_xrdb3`.`publication_author`, CONSTRAINT `employee_id_refs_emp_id_33542a34` FOREIGN KEY (`employee_id`) REFERENCES `employees` (`emp_id`))')
```

I suspect it's because table `employees` doesn't exist (it's actually a view). So the FK constraint throws an error.

This ought to be made to work, though. Can it?
I'm using MySQL, BTW.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible at the MySQL level:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-restrictions.html

Basically you can't create a foreign key to a column which is not indexed, and you can't created indexed columns on a view.

I have not tried it but you could look into this:
https://code.google.com/p/flexviews/

It's a way to create 'materialised' views in MySQL, as real tables, so you could then use that as the backing for your Django model and presumably foreign keys would work.